# Unable to connect to internet after applying static IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip-address

I have a wireless router and 2 PCs with wireless adapters. A DSL modem is connected to the router and everything works without configuring anything.

The PCs are connected and can share files with each other. I can access each computer on the other by their respective names.

The internet is working fine.

However, when I provide a static IP address to each computer under the TCP/IP settings, the internet stops working. Everything else still works. The IP addresses are 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set proper default gateway and DNS addresses too. You could use the ones that your router is configured with, or you could use the IP address of your router.

Answer (score 0):

Ki Ba's answer is likely correct, however the way you are setting statics is not the best way.

I am assuming your router is currently issuing the IP addresses for your devices?  Most routers have the option to provide the same IP address to the device each time via DHCP.  Look for the DHCP setting, and setting static IP addresses.  You will need the MAC address of each machine, which (if it isn't already present in the settings), you can get by doing

```
ipconfig /all
```

You are looking for the `Physical Address` of the Local Area Connection.  It will be in the form

```
aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff
```

However, usually routers require it in the form

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

So just swap the hyphens for whatever it needs.